# Get sum of Nested Array in Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Ok, I have an issue I cannot seem to solve.

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "playerId": "43345jhiuy3498jh4358yu345j",
  "leaderboardId": "5b165ca15399c020e3f17a75",
  "data": {
    "type": "EclecticData",
    "holeScores": [
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "xtraStrokes": 0,
        "strokes": 3,
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "xtraStrokes": 1,
        "strokes": 5,
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "xtraStrokes": 0,
        "strokes": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, what I am trying to accomplish is using aggregate sum the strokes and then order it afterwards. I am trying this:

```
var sortedBoard = db.collection.aggregate(
    {$match: {"leaderboardId": boardId}},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$playerId",
        played: { $sum: 1 },
        strokes: {$sum: '$data.holeScores.strokes'}
        }
    },
    {$project:{ 
        type: "$SortBoard",
        avgPoints: '$played',
        sumPoints: "$strokes",
        played : '$played'
    }}
);
```

The issue here is that I do net get the strokes sum correct, since this is inside another array.

Hope someone can help me with this and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to say [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) **twice**:

```
var sortedBoard = db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "leaderboardId": boardId}},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$playerId",
    "SortBoard": { "$first": "$SortBoard" },
    "played": { "$sum": 1 },
    "strokes": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$data.holeScores.strokes"} }
  }},
  { "$project": { 
    "type": "$SortBoard",
    "avgPoints": "$playeyed",
    "sumPoints": "$strokes",
    "played": "$played"
  }}
])
```

The reason is because you are using it **both** as a way to "sum array values" and also as an "accumulator" for [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

The other thing you appear to be missing is that [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) only outputs the fields you tell it to, therefore if you want to access other fields in other stages or output, you need to keep them with something like [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or another accumulator. We also appear to be missing a pipeline stage in the question anyway, but it's worth noting just to be sure.

Also note you really should wrap aggregation pipelines as an official array `[]`, because the legacy usage is deprecated and can cause problems in some language implementations.

Returns the correct details of course:

```
{
        "_id" : "43345jhiuy3498jh4358yu345j",
        "avgPoints" : 1,
        "sumPoints" : 12,
        "played" : 1
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was going for :-) Not sure what you mean about the official array?

Comment: @Mansa Look at the differences between your question and the answer. Then you should be sure.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that :-)